# Issues With Passport Authentication And Config

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, post, passport.js

I am working on a full stack web application and am setting up the register and login routes I have connected to a local mongodb for the user model and am now working on setting up a passport config to make authentication is easy (and just for practice in the library). The thing is, that even when I hard code return done(null, user); into the config, it still returns false.

To begin with, this is my login POST route for the login page:

```
router.post('/', async function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
        passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
            if (err) { return next(err); }
            if (!user) { return res.redirect('/'); }
            req.logIn(user, function(err) {
                if (err) { return next(err); }
                return res.redirect('/account');
            });
        })(req, res, next);
    }
});
```

This is my server.js code:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
    require('dotenv').config({ path: '.env' });
}

// Dependencies
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const session = require('express-session');
const app = express();

// Setup
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(session({ secret: 'yeet', resave: false, saveUninitialized: false }));

// Passport Setup
const passport = require('passport');
require('./config/passport')(passport);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// MongoDB
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, 'useCreateIndex': true });
mongoose.connection.on('error', error => console.log(error));
mongoose.connection.once('open', () => console.log("Connected To Database"));

// Routes
const indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
const trendingRouter = require('./routes/trending');
const accountRouter = require('./routes/account');

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/trending', trendingRouter);
app.use('/account', accountRouter);

// Port
app.listen(3030);
```

and this is my config file itself:

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const passport = require('passport');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const User = require('../models/User');

module.exports = function(passport) {
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
        function(username, password, done) {
            User.findOne({ userName: username }, function (err, user) {
                if (err) return done(err);
                if (!user) return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
                bcrypt.compare(password, user.userPassword, (err, isMatch) => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    if (isMatch) return done(null, user);
                    return done(null, false, { message: 'Password incorrect' });
                });
                return done(null, user);
            });
        }
      ));

    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });
    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
            done(err, user);
        });
    });
};
```

Now something interesting is, that I don't think my local config file is ever called. I have tried adding a console.log("test") into it, and that message never appears in the terminal. I have followed the docs though as closely as I can and have even gone through a series of tutorials to find my answers, but have come up empty handed.

What's my problem? Thank you for your time and answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was my input fields on my view were not called `username` and `password` as they should be per the docs. That will make it so that the config file can actually retrieve the necessary information from the input fields.